# gMonthDay difference

Tags: xslt

Can you answer this?

Why does this not work...

`<xsl:value-of select="xs:gMonthDay('--12-14') - xs:dayTimeDuration('P5D')">`

xs:date works when I change the values but xs:gMonthDay does not allow me to perform subtraction, addition etc why?

using xslt 2.0 saxon
thanks

Answer (score 1):

> Why does this not work...

because the spec doesn't allow it. XPath arithmetic and comparison operators are defined for xs:date and xs:dateTime but not for the gThingThing types.

Why doesn't the spec allow it? Because date/time handling was already accounting for a grossly disproportionate slice of the specification and the WG's time and effort.